# how to render multiple callback function to views in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynccallback

I have created two function which are fetching values from mongodb then i want to render these function to views but I can assign only function at a time but can't assign both function to render in views.
I want to know the best techniques to do the following.
Actually I want to display books from the category by the following url

```
http://localhost:3000/category/catid/56696ddeef90d5400b604361
```

This will fetch all books from category mentioned and all book category in sidebar as well.

my code is following

```
function get_books_details(callback){

  //console.log(get_cat_id);
  //res.render('pages/category', { title: 'Express','get_cat':get_cat_id});
  var get_books=[];
  var array = [];
    /* query mongodb start */
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
      } else {
          db.collection('book', function(err, collection) {
              collection.find().toArray(function(err,results) {                   
                  results.forEach(function(item) {                       
                    array.push(item);                       
                  });
                    callback(array);
               //     console.log(array);    
              });        
          });       

      } //else end
    });
    /* query mongodb end */ 
}

function get_cat_details(callback){

  //console.log(get_cat_id);
  //res.render('pages/category', { title: 'Express','get_cat':get_cat_id});
  var get_cats_call=[];
  var array_cats = [];
    /* query mongodb start */
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
      } else {
          db.collection('category', function(err, collection) {
              collection.find().toArray(function(err,results) {                   
                  results.forEach(function(itemcats) {                       
                    array_cats.push(itemcats);                      
                  });
                    callback(array_cats);
                  //console.log(array_cats);    
              });        
          });       

      } //else end
    });
    /* query mongodb end */ 
}


router.get('/catid/:catId', function(req, res) {
  var get_cat_id=req.params.catId;       

   get_books_details(function(data_book){
       console.log(data_book);
        res.render('pages/category', {title:"LNA Publication","allbuk":data_book,"get_category":get_cat_id});

    });

get_cat_details(function(data_cat){
       console.log(data_cat);
        res.render('pages/category', {title:"LNA Publication",itm:data_cat,"get_category":get_cat_id});         
    });       

});
```

CLI Screenshot of output Console
[Screenshot of command line interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deqv5.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
 router.get('/catid/:catId', function(req, res) {
   var get_cat_id=req.params.catId;       

   get_books_details(function(data_book){
       console.log(data_book);
       get_cat_details(function(data_cat){
          console.log(data_cat);
          res.render('pages/category', {title:"LNA Publication",itm:data_cat,"allbuk":data_book,"get_category":get_cat_id});         
       });   
    });  
});
```

Comment: @Narendra Sharma . You are welcome. You can accept the answer if it solved your question.